# Why ExpectedException is deprecated in Spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

On the one side, there is a new `@RunWith` annotation that lets to change unit test framework on the fly.
But on the other side Spring documentations says about `org.springframework.test.annotation.ExpectedException`:

- @deprecated as of Spring 3.1 in favor of using built-in support for declaring expected exceptions in the underlying testing framework (e.g., JUnit, TestNG, etc.)

As a result my code will depend on the unit test framework. Please explain it.

And the 2nd question. At the moment I implement tests with Spring `@RunWith` annotation. But I also add the jUnit specific `org.junit.Test` annotation to each test method. Again, if I understand correctly the best way - to write tests, so I could change for example jUnit onto TestNg. And Spring `@RunWith` helps me to do that. But how can I avoid using of the `org.junit.Test` annotation?

Comment: Is it even possible to switch between TestHG and JUnit on the fly?  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @StephenC: I've never heard of such a thing, and the only reason I can think of wanting anything like that would be to combine separate, legacy test suites written in the two frameworks into one. That doesn't sound like what's happening here, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@RunWith` isn't a Spring annotation. [It's a JUnit one](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html). It doesn't let you switch between JUnit and TestNG, as you seem to think. Instead, it lets you run JUnit tests in different ways, like with the addition of the Spring Test Framework. In that framework, Spring has provided `ExpectedException` for some time, but it's no longer needed because recent versions of both JUnit and TestNG provide that functionality now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a test which can run on both JUnit and TestNG, so your code is bound to be dependent on testing framework. @RunWith is not a Spring's annotation for running tests with different testing frameworks, it belongs to JUnit and used to run JUnit with other runners like SpringJUnit4Runner to extend JUnit functionality